# Esquemas de recursión en otras estructuras Haskell

Tags: haskell, estructuras

**Hace unos cuentos días que estoy trabado con este ejercicio:**

Dado el siguiente tipo de datos algebraico que representa las expresiones aritméticas entre números enteros que involucran sumas y productos:

```
data ExpA = Cte Int | Suma ExpA ExpA | Producto ExpA ExpA
```

Por ejemplo, la expresión `exp = (3 + (1 + 1) ∗ 5)` se representa de la siguiente forma:

```
exp = Suma (Cte 3) (Producto (Suma (Cte 1) (Cte 1)) (Cte 5))
```

i) Escribir el esquema de `fold` de `ExpA`. En este ejercicio se debe utilizar recursión explícita.

ii) Escribir la función `cantidadSumas :: ExpA −> Int`, que devuelve la cantidad de
sumas que aparecen en la expresión aritmética dada.

iii) Escribir la función `simplificarEA :: ExpA −> ExpA`, que dada una expresión aritmética, devuelve una expresión equivalente pero que no tiene sumas del número 0, ni multiplicaciones por 1 o por 0.

¿Alguien me podrá ayudar?

Comment: Si has probado algo, por favor muestra tu esfuerzo.

Comment: La solución es más fácil de lo que parece. Es uno de esos momentos en los que comprobarás que la programación funcional es otra cosa que nada tiene qué ver con la programación que conocías hasta ahora. Dínos qué has intentado y dónde te quedas atascado, pero sobre todo inténtalo hacer por tí mismo.

Answer (score 0):

```
data ExpA = Cte Int | Suma ExpA ExpA | Producto ExpA ExpA
```

*i) Escribir el esquema de fold de ExpA. En este ejercicio se debe utilizar recursión explícita.*

```
foldlExpA :: (int->a)->(a->a->a)->(a->a->a)Exp->a

foldlExpA f _ _ (Cte i) = fi

...
```

Answer (score -1):

La verdad me pasa lo mismo.
Creo que es algo así:

```
--Patter Matching

foldE f _ _ (Cte c) = f c
foldE f g h (Suma p1 p2) = g (foldE f g h p1) (foldE f g h p2)
foldE f g h (Producto p1 p2) = h (foldE f g h p1) (foldE f g h p2)
```

Siento que me quede atascado.

Comment: Es una respuesta o estás buscando ayuda?

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Esta parece una nueva pregunta. Puedes generar la misma y poner un enlace a esta, para establecer un contexto, ya que en el sitio, la zona de respuestas, se usa solo para respuestas explicitas a la pregunta. También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].